# Detect if PowerPoint slide is hidden

Tags: c#, .net, powerpoint, office-interop

I'm using Office Interop for controling PowerPoint presentation from my app and I need to detect if specific slide is marked as hidden. How to achieve that? I checked documentation for Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide, but none of Slide properties exposes this information.

Comment: How about SlideShowTransition.Hidden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the `SlideShowTransition` interface has a `Hidden` property that exposes this information:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.powerpoint.slideshowtransition(v=office.14).aspx

You can access this via `Slide.SlideShowTransition`